# Register form always give error " this field is required "

Tags: python, django

I want to make a register form, that contains user form and user profile form

my table user is from Django auth_user so it will contain primary column like id, user, email, password, started date, etc

and I have user profile form, that creates from forms.py and the model from model.py here, it has FK user_id which connected to ID in auth_user

the problem is, when I insert the data,  it always said this field required, even though I already insert all the column

here's the code

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')


class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ROLE_1 = 'Business Analyst'
    ROLE_2 = 'Manager'
    ROLE_3 = 'Segment Manager'
    ROLE_4 = 'Admin'
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (ROLE_1, u"Business Analyst"),
        (ROLE_2, u"Manager"),
        (ROLE_3, u"Segment Manager"),
        (ROLE_4, u"Admin")
    )
    role = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    cell = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    def __init__(self, disable_fields=True, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if disable_fields:
            self.fields['role'].disabled = True
```

models.py

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    cell = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

```
def register(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("test")
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=false)
            profile.user = user
            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']
            profile.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(disable_fields=False)
    return render(request, 'register.html',
                  {'user_form': user_form,
                   'profile_form': profile_form,
                   'registered': registered})
```

html

```
<section id="main-content">
      <section class="wrapper">
        <h3><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Register User</h3>
        <!-- row -->
        <!-- FORM VALIDATION -->
        <div class="row mt">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-panel">
              <div class=" form">
                 {% load staticfiles %}
                          {% block body_block %}

                                {% if registered %}
                                  <h1>Thank you for registering!</h1>
                                {% else %}





                    <form class=" form-horizontal style-form" id="commentForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">

                                    {% csrf_token %}

                                    {{ user_form.as_p}}

                                    {{ profile_form.as_p }}



                    <button class="btn btn-theme" type="submit" style="height:50px;width:200px;" value="Register">Register</button> 


                     </form>

                 {% endif %}
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          {% endblock %}
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /form-panel -->
          </div>
          <!-- /col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /row -->
      </section>
    </section>
```

can someone help me? i already try some way like remove the profile_form.isvalid() in the if condition, and it goes to the next step, but it is error `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("ICB"."POLLS_USERPROFILEINFO"."USER_ID")` which user_id is the fk

at first .. I make this module and it works fine, but 1 month later it errors, and I didn't change any code

Answer (score 0):

Try edit this section in your html:

```html
action="your_url_here"
```

Comment: when it raised `this field is requried` error, did the log raise a specific field?

Comment: The next potential problem is that you forget to apply your `Meta` class to your `userprofileinfoform` since you didn't specify which fields to include.

Comment: password field , but i thin kthe problem is not there because the user form is valid , the one who has problem is the userprofileinfo form because userprofileinfo model has userid who references from user model ..

Comment: class `Meta` is what I mean

Comment: hmm okay i will try explore it first , thankyou for the suggestion